How to extract jwt claims in springboot
public Claims extractClaims(String token) {
        SecretKey key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(secretKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        return Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(key)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }


This is the method I am using to extract claims from jwt token. But compiler is giving error that "No candidates found for method call Jwts. parser() .setSigningKey(key) .parseClaimsJws(token).". It is unable to resolve ".parseClaimsJws(token)" method. I am using jwt version 0.12.5.

correct would be:
        return Jwts.parser()
                .verifyWith(key)
                .build()
                .parseSignedClaims(token)
                .getPayload();

see documentation
